# NOTE: 'pm list' commands have moved! Run 'adb shell cmd package'

Tags: adb, shell

When I tried:

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```

I got long list of options with:

```
NOTE: 'pm list' commands have moved! Run 'adb shell cmd package'
```

What is `cmd` and is it new place for Android's parameters discovery?

Comment: To summarize, the `pm list` command is now `cmd packages`. Try running it with `adb shell cmd packages`.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman the correct syntax is "cmd package list packages".

Comment: @user218076 True, but what I said is that `pm list` (without further arguments) equals `cmd package`: by running either, you get an usage message. My comment addressed the "what is cmd" part.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman ok. I understand. I just figured I'll clarify it. I had struggled with figuring this out. Since I thought you responded to his question. So I tried cmd packages but got an error. It is cmd package with out the "s". Thanks